# White blink when creating new window?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating this program that it's not complete yet, a small detail that annoys me, when you run the program and click "OPEN" it creates a new Toplevel window inside the `def click_selettore` function in the beginning, and i notice that the black screen on the left "blinks" for a split second, for a split second is white and then it become black i hope you notice this, the photo attached it's a frame of the Toplevel opening window and i notice the white frames that are loading i think, and they are white for a split second. How to solve this and not making the new window white for the split second? Thanks, here is the code it's a bit long but the probelm is only the white blinks when creating the window inside the "click selettore" function, if you help me i would really appreciate it

[image]

```
from tkinter import *
import customtkinter
from ctypes import windll
windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)
def click_selettore(event):
    bg = "#414141"
    win.attributes('-topmost', 0)
    win2 = Toplevel(win)
    win2.focus()
    win2.resizable(False,False)
    win2.grab_set()
    win2.configure(bg=bg)
    win2.title("Selettore colori")
    frame_schermo = Frame(win2)
    frame_schermo.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=(20,0),pady=(20,0))
    schermo = Label(frame_schermo, bg="#000000", width=45, height=9, relief="solid", borderwidth=3)
    schermo.grid(row=0,column=0)
    frame_slider = Frame(win2,bg=bg)
    frame_slider.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=N,pady=(20,0),padx=(50,0))
    etc_rosso = Label(frame_slider, text="Rosso", bg=bg, fg="#C70000", font=("Ink Free", 20, "bold"))
    etc_rosso.grid(row=0,column=0,pady=(11,0))
    slider_rosso = customtkinter.CTkSlider(frame_slider, from_=0, to=255,width=230,progress_color='#C70000',fg_color='#a34949',button_hover_color='#3f9feb',button_color='#1f82d1')
    slider_rosso.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=N,padx=(10,0),pady=(23,0))
    slider_rosso.set(0)
    casella_rosso = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=frame_slider,text_font=('Courier',15,'bold'),width=55)
    casella_rosso.grid(row=0,column=2,pady=(11,0),padx=(7,20))
    casella_rosso.insert(0,0)
    etc_verde = Label(frame_slider, text="Verde", bg=bg, fg="#3fc441", font=("Ink Free", 20, "bold"))
    etc_verde.grid(row=1,column=0,pady=(11,0))
    slider_verde = customtkinter.CTkSlider(frame_slider, from_=0, to=255, width=230, progress_color='#3fc441', fg_color='#3d803e', button_hover_color='#3f9feb', button_color='#1f82d1')
    slider_verde.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=N,padx=(10,0),pady=(23,0))
    slider_verde.set(0)
    casella_verde = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=frame_slider, text_font=('Courier', 15, 'bold'), width=55)
    casella_verde.grid(row=1, column=2,pady=(11,0),padx=(7,20))
    casella_verde.insert(0, 0)
    etc_blu = Label(frame_slider, text="Blu", bg=bg, fg="#010178", font=("Ink Free", 20, "bold"))
    etc_blu.grid(row=2,column=0,pady=(11,0))
    slider_blu = customtkinter.CTkSlider(frame_slider, from_=0, to=255, width=230, progress_color='#010178',fg_color='#222275', button_hover_color='#3f9feb', button_color='#1f82d1')
    slider_blu.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=N,padx=(10,0),pady=(23,0))
    slider_blu.set(0)
    casella_blu = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=frame_slider, text_font=('Courier', 15, 'bold'), width=55)
    casella_blu.grid(row=2, column=2,pady=(11,0),padx=(7,20))
    casella_blu.insert(0, 0)
    frame_sotto_slider = Frame(win2,bg=bg)
    frame_sotto_slider.grid(row=1,column=0,pady=(45,0),padx=(35,0))
    etc_esadecimale_titolo= Label(frame_sotto_slider,text='Esadecimale -> ',font=('Courier',16),fg='white',bg=bg)
    etc_esadecimale_titolo.grid(row=0,column=0)
    campo_esadecimale = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=frame_sotto_slider,text_font=('Courier',16),width=105)
    campo_esadecimale.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=(6,0))
    btn_ok = customtkinter.CTkButton(win2,text='Ok',text_font=('Courier',16),width=50,corner_radius=10,hover_color='#3a76a6')
    btn_ok.grid(row=3,column=1,sticky=E,pady=(50,10),padx=(0,10))
    win.eval(f'tk::PlaceWindow {str(win2)} center')
    win2.mainloop()
win = Tk()
win.configure(bg="#2b2b2b")
etichetta_selettore_colori = Label(win,text='OPEN',relief="solid",borderwidth=4,font=('Helvetica',17))
etichetta_selettore_colori.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=(20,0),pady=20)
etichetta_selettore_colori.bind("<Button-1>",click_selettore)
win.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please try to reduce the code down to a [mcve]. There's a lot of code that probably isn't necessary to reproduce this problem.

Comment: HI @BryanOakley, ok i rediced the code a lot, basically the problem is that when i click "open" and the function "click_selettore" runs, sometimes i notice that the widget in the function are white for a split second and then they are loaded, as you can see in the image it's a frame of the opening function catched in a video. Is there a way to remove this blink? I noticed that doesn't happen always, don't really understand, thanks